# Trying to use setter to add a label to the string being stored

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an @property and a setter for that property. I need the setter to concatenate a label onto the string and save it as the new string object. Here is the property and setter I am referring to:

```
@property
def thesis(self):
    """Returns thesis in all capital letters"""
    return self.__thesis.upper()

@thesis.setter
def thesis(self, thesis):
    """Setter adds the label 'Thesis '"""

    self.__thesis = 'THESIS: ' + thesis
```

As you can see, I am trying to add a label ('THESIS: ') to the thesis string parameter and then save that new string as self.__thesis. This is not working for me. When the thesis is printed to the screen later on, the only thing that shows up is the thesis without the label. I have tried messing around with the name mangling as well as different ways to concatenate the string and nothing has worked. Thank you in advance!

Someone asked how I am printing the thesis to the screen. First the thesis object is overriden and formatted in def **str**(self):

```
    def __str__(self):
    """Overrides overridden __str__() from our super class Student.
    Gets the full name calling supper class and gets thesis"""

    return f'{super().__str__()}\n\t{self.__thesis.upper()}'
```

It calls the super class which has objects for first and last name, and then get's the thesis. Each student object, including their first/last name, and thesis if applicable are saved to a list called ***students***. To actually print the formatted string above, I just loop through each student in students:

```
    for s in students:
    print(s)
    if isinstance(s, PhDStudent): # ignore this
        print(f'\t{s.dissertation}') # ignore this
```

I created the thesis instance in the initializer function of the class GradStudent(Student):

```
class GradStudent(Student):
"""GradStudent is derived/inherits from the Student class.
Extends Student by adding thesis question"""

def __init__(self, thesis, first_name=''):
    # calls super class (Student's initializer) and passes first_name argument
    super().__init__(first_name)
    self.__thesis = thesis
```

Comment: How are you printing the thesis to the screen?

Comment: I can't figure out the formatting here so I'll add it to the original post

Comment: Where are you creating the thesis instance? It should look like this test = Thesis().
I'm asking because your code worked as expected for me but I was able to reproduce the error if I wrote this instead test = Thesis. With the parens, you're creating a new instance of the class (this is what you want to do). Without the parens, you're assigning to the class definition. I'm not saying that's the mistake you're making, just that when I made that mistake, I got the same results you're getting.

Comment: @NicholasHunter I created the thesis instance in the initializer function of the class that all of this code comes from. I'll also add this to the original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Class definition

```
class Student:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__thesis = None
        
    @property
    def thesis(self):
        """Returns thesis in all capital letters"""
        return self.__thesis.upper()

    @thesis.setter
    def thesis(self, value):
        """Setter adds the label 'Thesis '"""

        self.__thesis = 'THESIS: ' + value
```

## This works as expected

```
test = Student()
test.thesis = "Test"
print (test.thesis)
```

Result: THESIS: TEST

## This fails the same way your code is failing

```
test = Student
test.thesis = "Test"
print (test.thesis)
```

Result: Test

Answer (score 1):

Your `__init__` method is not using the setter of your property because you've written it to directly access the underlying attribute `self.__thesis` instead of going through the property's setter. That means that any thesis value you pass in to the constructor will not have the prefix added.

You can fix this by having your `__init__` method use `self.thesis`:

```
def __init__(self, thesis, first_name=''):
    super().__init__(first_name)
    self.thesis = thesis   # don't use double underscores here!
```

Note that you may want `__str__` to access the getter of the property too, rather than repeating the capitalization code again while accessing `self.__thesis`.

I'd note that it's seldom a sign of good Python class design to have lots of `__name_mangled` variables. That smells like code that was designed with another language in mind (like C++ or Java), where private instance variables are the norm. It's much more conventional in Python to use normal variables without any leading underscores for most things, and to use only a single leading underscore when you want to hide the internal value (such as a value that underlies a property). Name mangling with `__double_underscore_prefixed_names` is intended for use by mixin or proxy types that need to avoid name collisions with unknown other types that will have unknown attributes sharing their namespaces.

Comment: Yeah, the excessive use of name mangling unfortunately comes from the project requirements. I guess he want's us to understand how they work. Thanks for the reply man, I'm gonna try it out right now and get back to you

Comment: This one didn't quite work out due the sheer amount of name mangles variables that I had to use in this program. Appreciate it tho

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It should work for any number of properties. My suggestion about avoiding `__mangled_names` is secondary to the main point of the answer, your code can work fine without that as long as you're actually *using* the property setter any time you need to assign a value.